# How to replace a selected text in synedit?

Tags: delphi-2009, synedit

I'm doing a custom text editor in Delphi with SynEdit and i'm at a loss with a simple need:

I want to have a popup button that, when clicked, replace the selected text with an uppercase version of that text. I think i have to use SelStart y SelEnd, but i'm not sure how can i do it.

I went into google and find mentions of a "La biblia de SynEdit" but the links were dead, so i ended here, hoping for a helpful soul who can answer my questions or has a copy of that bible.

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed, thx! Yuou should post it as an answer so i can give you credit for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `SelStart` to the beginning of the text, and `SelLength` to the length of that text (or, alternatatively, set `SelEnd` to the end of the text), and then assign your new text using `SelText`. This is the same way it works in the VCL.TRichEdit component.

```
SynEdit1.SelStart := 1;
SynEdit1.SelLength := Length(NewText);
SynEdit1.SelText := NewText;
```